# Is the set of SOLID principles missing an extra 'D'?

Tags: oop, dry, solid-principles

Although not a pure [OOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OOD) principle - should [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) also be included when thinking about [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(Object_Oriented_Design)) principles? If not - why not?

Comment: *An aside:* adding an extra 'D' to SOLID yields only one candidate acronym that is also an English word. This in itself could be a good reason to keep DRY out of SOLID.

Comment: @teabot: it would still be fairly easy to remember it.

Comment: +1 nice thought provoking question

Comment: @teabot It's probably because I'm horrible at Scrabble but I cannot come up with a word with SOLID + D.

Comment: @Davy8 google scrabble word finder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit like asking why you shouldn't add a monkey-wrench to a basket of apples: they're not really the same thing.

SOLID is a set of principles that specifically address object-oriented design.

DRY is, I'd say, somewhat orthogonal to those - it's a programming principle that can apply to anything you write.

(Having said that, the acronym is almost too good to pass up on)

Answer (score 2):

I think "DRY" is probably not specific enough to make it into SOLID.  "DRY" might be an underlying principle of the other principles, and it applies to any kind of development, not just object-oriented development, like SOLID does.

Answer (score 0):

SOLID embraces DRY. If you ahdhere to the SOLID principles you are almost automatically DRY.